# Measure EPS (Events per Seconds)

Tags: performance, logging, event-log, syslog, events

I want to measure the EPS metric, or the number of processed events per seconds in my device.

I read that **the most accurate measurement of EPS is to use a simple syslog server, such as Kiwi Syslog Server, and measure actual EPS over a period of time.**

From what I can gather, this means that I have to configure my Syslog server to receive data from my device, and capture the logs in a specified folder. I also read in another source, that I need to run the syslog 24 hours and calculate the EPS (using the simple formula EPS = Number of System Events / Time Period in Seconds).

My question is this: I don't get how the Syslog server will help determine the EPS ? Because all what I'll get after the 24h, is the number of logs generated in the 24 hours in the specified folder! Or am I missing something ?

**PS : This is NOT a question about a specific vendor or a device, but rather a question to understand this general concept in using Syslog to measure EPS.**